# js objects and properties

Tags: javascript

How Could I list/loop all properties of an object? Knowing only the object name.

eg

```
for(var prop in myobject){
 alert(prop.name);
 alert(prop.value);
}
```

Comment: Use prop as a key into the myobject properties i.e. myobject[prop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(var prop in myobject) {
    alert(prop);
    alert(myobject[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Remember to use `.hasOwnProperty`

Comment: I was just tying to see google map marker properties. (api2)
Works thanks, except there are many of properties!
document.write might be better next time instead of alert. oops

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there!

```
for(var prop in myobject){
  alert(prop);           // -> property name
  alert(myobject[prop]); // -> property value
}
```

Be aware that this will only iterate over properties that don't have the `{DontEnum}` attribute.  Almost all built-in properties and methods will not be iterated over, you will only see custom properties and methods added either directly or via the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

```
myobj.prototype.details= function(delim, sortfun){
    delim=delim || ', ';
    var list= [];
    for(var p in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(p){
            list[list.length]=p+':'+this[p].toString();
        }
    }
    if(typeof sortfun==function) list.sort(sortfun);   
    return list.join(delim);
}
```

f