# How to get the keys of an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there any function to get the keys of an array using javascript

Also i want to reverse and array

eg:

> appz_variable['412cc16e']="ABXZ";
>
> appz_variable['axecr6fd']="YCSET";

I want the array indexes or keys in reverse order

Comment: Arrays are usually indexed by integers. So what keys are you talking about? Are you talking about hashes? Please provide an example.

Comment: Dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980242/js-objects-and-properties, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javasctipt-object-key-list, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume here you're talking about an object which some label (albeit incorrectly) an "associative array".  For that situation, use a `for...in` loop to enumerate the object, like this:

```
for(var key in myObject) {
  if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + myObject[key]);
  }
}
```

For a normal array you just loop though based on an index, like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
  alert("Position: " + i + ", Value: " + myArray[i]);
}
```

The second is *iterating* over the array, while the first is *enumerating* the object...you shouldn't use a `for...in` loop on a normal array for example, as there are many problems that can arise.

Comment: can u please tell me. how to. reverse an array using the first method

Comment: @Nick Craver - I just updated my question please go through it

Comment: @Anish - Yeah...that order isn't guaranteed, the best you can do is loop through, you can store and presents the results backwards, but **it may very by browser**, so I wouldn't count on the ordering (especially in IE).

Comment: I am using php to create that array . So even if I send a reversed array from php it wont be in the same order ???

Comment: @Anish - nope, not necessarily, as I said this isn't an array, it's an object.

Answer (score -1):

You can index your array by numbers when it is created. perhaps like this:

```
appz_variable[0]['412cc16e']="ABXZ";
appz_variable[1]['axecr6fd']="YCSET";
```

and then you will have an "order" which you can then reverse...